# Which implementation of a factorial function is generally faster in Java?

Tags: java, optimization

I am thinking about two possible implementations of the factorial function. I am not sure which one is, in general, faster. I can think of arguments for why either might be faster. (I am not actually trying to implement a fast factorial function; I am just curious about this.)

Method 1:

```
public static BigInteger factorial (int n) {
     BigInteger product = new BigInteger("1");
     for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
          product = product.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
     }
     return product;     
}
```

Method 2:

```
public static BigInteger factorial (int n) {
     BigInteger product = new BigInteger("1");
     for (int i = n; i>=1; i--) {
          product = product.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
     }
     return product;     
}
```

Essentially, method 1 performs the multiplication 1*2*...*n, as (( 1 * 2 )* 3)*..., and method 2 computes the product of the same terms, but in the reverse order: (( n * (n-1) ) * (n-2) )*...

**My question is:** which of these will generally have the faster runtime?

I know it is slower to multiply larger numbers, but is it faster, when multiplying many terms together, to keep the value of the product relatively small for as long as possible (method 1) or to perform the multiplication with the largest terms while the total product is still smaller (method 2)?

Does it depend on the size of `n`? Would the answer  be different if I used `long` or `int` instead of `BigInteger` (barring overflow), or if I worked in another language?

Comment: Intuitively I think the order would make negligible, if any at all, performance difference, but the only way to find out is to actually benchmark it. Give it a sufficiently large n and see how it goes.

Comment: Using `long` will most likely be faster, before it overflows anyway.

Comment: I would expect little difference between these two different loops. The number of iterations is the same as is the work done within the loop. Using primitive types rather than objects for this computation would probably be much faster.

Comment: The order of multiplicands matter, but no matter where you start, after a while you multiply one huge number with a much smaller multiplier. So there's not much to gain. Grouping the number like `((1*2) * (3*4)) * ...` helps a lot. For a much faster implementation see [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.java#L388).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with *n* = 100,000, and found that, after a few runs to warm up, low-to-high was consistently somewhat faster than high-to-low, *but* that both approaches were beaten by a large margin by an approach of the form ((1×2)×(3×4)) × ((5×6)×(7×8)) — multiplying pairs of adjacent numbers, then pairs of adjacent results, etc., until finally there's one answer — with the goal of having the great majority of the multiplications be of small numbers.

This makes sense when you consider that multiplication with a larger number is more expensive (all else being equal) than multiplication with a smaller number. Compared to the low-to-high approach, the high-to-low approach quickly increases the product by many orders of magnitude (the tenth multiplication is already on the order of 10<sup>50</sup> instead of 10<sup>6.5</sup>), and the product in the low-to-high approach never "catches up" until the very final result. So almost every single multiplication along the way is cheaper in the low-to-high approach, sometimes by a large margin.

As an additional check, I wrote some logic to track the rough "cost" of a given approach assuming that the "cost" of a given multiplication is roughly the number of bits in the result:

```
private static BigInteger multiply(final BigInteger a, final BigInteger b) {
    final BigInteger product = a.multiply(b);
    cost += product.bitLength();
    return product;
}
```

For *n* = 100,000, the low-to-high approach has a total "cost" of 72,229,688,834; the high-to-low approach has a total "cost" of 79,442,345,171 (about 11% higher); and the repeatedly-split-in-half approach has a total "cost" of 25,362,728 (about 96% lower). That agrees with the timings I saw.

---

Here's a typical run (including warmup, etc.):

```
$ javac SO62307487.java && java SO62307487 100000
  low-to-high: 1516705 bits in 3547.334ms.
  high-to-low: 1516705 bits in 3688.083ms.
split-in-half: 1516705 bits in  175.483ms.

  low-to-high: 1516705 bits in 3892.075ms.
  high-to-low: 1516705 bits in 3805.003ms.
split-in-half: 1516705 bits in  116.792ms.

  low-to-high: 1516705 bits in 3444.635ms.
  high-to-low: 1516705 bits in 3976.932ms.
split-in-half: 1516705 bits in   97.262ms.

  low-to-high: 1516705 bits in 3689.550ms.
  high-to-low: 1516705 bits in 3746.681ms.
split-in-half: 1516705 bits in   95.459ms.

  low-to-high: 1516705 bits in 3474.545ms.
  high-to-low: 1516705 bits in 3706.841ms.
split-in-half: 1516705 bits in   96.370ms.

  low-to-high: 1516705 bits in 3427.387ms.
  high-to-low: 1516705 bits in 3700.014ms.
split-in-half: 1516705 bits in   95.865ms.

  low-to-high: 1516705 bits in 3491.601ms.
  high-to-low: 1516705 bits in 3699.362ms.
split-in-half: 1516705 bits in   95.737ms.

  low-to-high: 1516705 bits in 3453.318ms.
  high-to-low: 1516705 bits in 3649.198ms.
split-in-half: 1516705 bits in   95.564ms.

  low-to-high: 1516705 bits in 3436.716ms.
  high-to-low: 1516705 bits in 3698.135ms.
split-in-half: 1516705 bits in   95.649ms.

  low-to-high: 1516705 bits in 3443.338ms.
  high-to-low: 1516705 bits in 3732.814ms.
split-in-half: 1516705 bits in   95.193ms.
```

As you can see, the exact timing varies, but not very much (aside from the first few iterations); the numbers are really pretty consistent, with approach #1 being consistently under 3.5 seconds and approach #2 being consistently over 3.6 seconds . . . and approach #3 being consistently under 0.1 seconds.

With smaller values of *n* (1000 and 10,000), I observed the same trend, but with more noise.

---

Full code (for just the timing comparisons, not the "cost" stuff):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public final class SO62307487 {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            timeIt("  low-to-high", () -> factoralFromLowToHigh(n));
            timeIt("  high-to-low", () -> factoralFromHighToLow(n));
            timeIt("split-in-half", () -> factorialBySplitInHalf(n));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void timeIt(final String id, final Supplier<BigInteger> supplier) {
        final long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
        final BigInteger result = supplier.get();
        final long endNanos = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf(
            "%s: %d bits in %8.3fms.%n",
            id, result.bitLength(), (endNanos - startNanos) / 1000000.0);
    }

    private static BigInteger factoralFromLowToHigh(final int n) {
        BigInteger product = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            product = product.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        return product;
    }

    private static BigInteger factoralFromHighToLow(final int n) {
        BigInteger product = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i = n; i >= 1 ; --i) {
            product = product.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        return product;
    }

    private static BigInteger factorialBySplitInHalf(final int n) {
        return helpSplitInHalf(1, n);
    }

    private static BigInteger helpSplitInHalf(final int first, final int last) {
        if (first == last) {
            return BigInteger.valueOf(first);
        }
        final int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
        return helpSplitInHalf(first, mid).multiply(helpSplitInHalf(mid + 1, last));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran the two different takes through [JMH](https://mkyong.com/java/java-jmh-benchmark-tutorial/), which is how you should benchmark java code, as it takes care of mitigating the effects of hotspot warmup and the like:

```
n = 100
platform: JDK11, intel x86-64 2,9Ghz core i5 laptop.
Benchmark               Mode  Cnt       Score       Error  Units
MyBenchmark.highToLow  thrpt   25  175954,070 ± 20689,017  ops/s
MyBenchmark.lowToHigh  thrpt   25  184311,758 ± 18965,592  ops/s
```

It looks like low to high wins, but it doesn't - this is the same number, that's statistical noise.

with a much larger n, and reducing the iteration and runtime counts some to get you a speedy answer:

```
n = 10000
platform: JDK11, intel x86-64 2,9Ghz core i5 laptop.
Benchmark               Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
MyBenchmark.highToLow  thrpt    6  34,683 ±  7,075  ops/s
MyBenchmark.lowToHigh  thrpt    6  31,230 ± 21,437  ops/s
```

This boils down to the same; that's not significant.

Equally fast, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

Did some time mapping on scala code which is same as Java and looks like

```
object RecursiveFactorial {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val no = 100
    Util.time {
      factorial1(no)
    }
    Util.time {
      factorialN(1,no)
    }
  }

  def factorial1(n:Long) : Long = {
    if ((n == 1) || (n == 0) )
    {1}
    else {n * factorial1(n - 1)}
  }

  def factorialN(i:Long, n:Long) : Long = {
    if (i == n )
    {n}
    else {i * factorialN (i + 1,n)}
  }

}
// Elapsed time: 1038959ns // for factorialN
// Elapsed time: 17645ns   // for factorial1
```

it seems the factorial with 1*..*n will be faster than n*..*1 at least in case of recursion

Comment: That looks like a lot of complex code in loops with function calls and I would not expect it to be faster. Do you have timing data?

Comment: Will a recursive solution do ? @RichardChambers

Comment: It will do however none of this actually answers the posted question. You are just providing alternative code solutions that you think are better.

Comment: added some time nos. using scala code @RichardChambers